# Ghostscript slow on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, ghostscript

I have a perl-TK CGI program that builds a .eps file using perl Tk’s postscript method.
The .eps file is a 720x290 scatter-plot with 5760 (720x8) data points.
The .eps file size is 1273 KB; the resulting .png file size is 45 KB.

I’m calling ghostscript to convert the .eps file  to a .png file.

Ghostscript (latest version is 9.20) on the Raspberry Pi IS VERY SLOW.

```
TOP shows gs is CPU bound!
    VIRT=51816
    RES=38292
    SHR=11160
    S=R
    %CPU=100.0
    %MEM=4.0
```

The gs conversion takes about 24 seconds on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B to complete!

I’ve run the identical perl-TK CGI script with latest ghostscript (9.22 on Windows 8.1) on my PC.
The gs conversion there takes about 3.7 seconds.
The Raspberry Pi flavor of gs is taking 6.4 times as long to complete!

Interestingly, to build the .eps file under perl-TK takes .64 seconds on the Pi vs .26 seconds on Windows.
In this case, the Raspberry Pi 3 is taking only 2.4 times as long to complete.

The specific gs command I’m using looks like…

```
$GS executable for Raspbian is /usr/bin/gs
$GS executable for Windows 8.1 is C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin/gswin64c.exe


$GS -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72 sOutputFile=Boiler-WebApp.png -fBoiler-WebApp.eps
```

For titles, axis labels, and graph keys, I’m using a minimalistic set of fonts (only NimbusSans) and verified that all fonts are loaded without substitutions.

So, is there anything I might be able to tweak with gs parameters to give the Raspberry Pi a performance boost?  Is it possible the x64 9.22 flavor of gs on the PC  is that much faster than 9.20 under x32 Raspbian?

My Windows PC specifics…
Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q6600 @2.4GHz with 6.00 GB memory, x64

My Raspberry Pi 3 Model B specifics…

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Answer (score 0):

So much depends on the content of the EPS file, which you have not supplied, and the way that the binary for the Raspberyy has been compiled.

You are comparing two totally different CPU architectures, using two different compilers and potentially at least using assembly language and SSE2 optimisations with the Intel CPU which aren't present on the ARM.

So comparing the two isn't so much apples and oranges, more like apples and Orang-utans. I also don't think that comparing a CPU-bound application with your perl script which is more likely bound by memory or disk overheads exhibits anything very much.

I'd suggest that 1.2MB is a pretty large EPS file and the use of text *and* graphics alpha is going to hurt performance a lot.

But it looks to me like you've simply run up against the fact that the Intel CPU has a lot more horsepower (its also a **lot** more expensive!)

I don't believe there's anything you can change on the command line that's going to get you more performance on the Model B, except possibly dropping the text and graphics alpha, which probably doesn't have a lot of effect at 72 dpi anyway.

**If** the SSE2 optimisations are being used (can't tell, because I haven't seen the file) then that might explain the difference, I don't know if the ARM chip being used has an equivalent, if so you could rewrite the assembly language to use the ARM op codes instead.

You should probably check the compiler optimisations used to compile the binary. If compiler optimisations are off then that would cost you quite a bit of performance.